# how to make an image carousel for JQM based website

Tags: jquery, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I have tried lot of image carousels for my mobile websites but none of them are giving proper result.

What I wanted was something like this website http://m.zoopla.co.uk/to-rent/details/17936879

If you open above link in a mobile device you can see the carousel. If the images are larger they are cut and centered and then zoomed to fit the window. I am trying to do something like that but it's not happening.

[image]

As you can see in the above image . Between the image carousal and page number there is white gap . I want to resize the image in such a way that I can fill the gaps with the image . Without loosing aspect ratio 
Please help me out if any one have idea about this website

Comment: How about checking the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I could get the result what I was trying to do . And instead of JS I got a css snippet which helped me zoom the smaller images to the div size without distorting the images much here is the small css code

```
.small{
transform:scale(1.42,1.42);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.42,1.42);
-moz-transform: scale(1.42,1.42);
-o-transform:  scale(1.42,1.42);
-ms-transform:  scale(1.42,1.42);

transition: all 0.65s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.65s;
-moz-transition: all 0.65s;
-o-transition:  all 0.65s;
-ms-transition:  all 0.65s;
}
```

Just add this to the image tag and it works fine.

**Note:**To work this css method effectively the image has to be centered to the div properly [image]

As you can see in the snapshot the image is zoomed in

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the OWL Carousel: http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html

To make the image 'zoom' you just set the `max-height` and `max-width` css attributes, e.g.:

```
#owl-demo .item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/LLDrJ/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to use similar carousel when you can one you so on that page.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PFqVs/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/photoswipe.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://thecodingwebsite.com/tutorials/photoswipe/klass.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>            
        <script src="http://thecodingwebsite.com/tutorials/photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.4.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <ul class="gallery">           
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/001.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/001.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/002.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/002.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/003.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/003.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/004.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/004.jpg" alt="Image 004" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/005.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/005.jpg" alt="Image 005" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/006.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/006.jpg" alt="Image 006" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/007.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/007.jpg" alt="Image 007" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/008.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/008.jpg" alt="Image 008" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/full/009.jpg" rel="external"><img src="http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/images/thumb/009.jpg" alt="Image 009" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){   
    var myPhotoSwipe = $(".gallery li a").photoSwipe({
        jQueryMobile: true,
        loop: false,
        enableMouseWheel: false,
        enableKeyboard: false
    });

    myPhotoSwipe.show(0);      
});
```

#### Note:

If you want to use newer version go to their github site: https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe , original developer is no longer working on this code so don't use code found at official site: [**www.photoswipe.com**](http://www.photoswipe.com)